# Remote API for docker exec commands

Tags: docker

Could someone please help me with remote api for docker exec to run a command?

I am able to run it directly:

```
# docker exec 941430a3060c date
Fri Apr 29 05:18:03 UTC 2016
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem?

Comment: I want to execute a command on a running container. For ex: date, ls etc. I know the CLI mentioned above works. I need to implement the same using remote API

Answer (score 3):

You have to follow below steps. I am adding rest api way. You can code it to any language.

1. **EXEC CREATE**

> POST /containers/(id or name)/exec

Body

```
{
  "AttachStdin": false,
  "AttachStdout": true,
  "AttachStderr": true,
  "Cmd": ["bash","-c","echo '*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /app/yii cronrun/job001'>> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"]
}
```

You have to select `Content-Type: application/json`

when you POST the above data you will get id in response. You have to use the id in next step.

*The above will add cron job in container which will execute every five minute.

---

2. **EXEC START**

> POST /exec/(id)/start

```
{
 "Detach": false,
 "Tty": false
}
```

You have to select `Content-Type: application/json`

Check response code, 200 is OK

Answer (score 1):

The API section which would help you is: [`Exec Create/Start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#exec-create)

You can see some example in [`integration-cli/docker_api_exec_test.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/integration-cli/docker_api_exec_test.go)

- [`create`](http://createExec):

  ```
  sockRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf("/containers/%s/exec", name), map[string]interface{}{"Cmd": []string{"true"}})
  ```
- [`start`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/integration-cli/docker_api_exec_test.go#L167):

  ```
  sockRequestRaw("POST", fmt.Sprintf("/exec/%s/start", id), strings.NewReader(`{"Detach": true}`), "application/json")
  ```
- [`inspect`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/integration-cli/docker_api_exec_test.go#L177):

  ```
  sockRequestRaw("GET", fmt.Sprintf("/exec/%s/json", id), nil, "")
  ```

Comment: Yes, i did this.. But where can i get the output of the command ?

Comment: @JayashreeRamamoorthy That is what the last inspect GET command is supposed to do.