# How to enable remote api for running docker container in local server

Tags: rest, api, docker, tensorflow, docker-machine

I am running a docker container with tensor-flow server locally. When i give this command line inside the docker machine (VM, Ubuntu 16.04)

```
root@d3f896a1dde6:~$ python client.py --server=172:17.0.2:9000

outputs {
key: “detection_boxes”
value {
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
dim {
size: 1
}
dim {
size: 300
}
dim {
size: 4
}
}
float_val: 0.24750074744224548
float_val: 0.17159424722194672
float_val: 0.9083144068717957
float_val: 0.797699511051178
outputs {
key: "detection_classes"
value {
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
dim {
size: 1
}
dim {
size: 300
}
}
float_val: 85.0
outputs {
key: "detection_scores"
value {
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
dim {
size: 1
}
dim {
size: 300
}
}
float_val: 0.9963208436965942
```

it produces an output inside the docker machine. I want to show this output on the web by enabling Remote API . Since i am completely new to this, I don't know how to proceed.

1) When i give http://172.17.0.2:9000 on browser,

> This site can’t be reached

2) I did port forwarding and tried with docker ip machine  http://198.162.99.100:9000, it gives me the same error

But i can ping these two from `cmd`

My question is, how do i show this output on the web page ? Also i want to automate this without typing `python client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000` inside the docker machine, so that i get  this output on the webpage directly. I followed this blog to create and run containers inside the docker machine https://weiminwang.blog/2017/09/12/introductory-guide-to-tensorflow-serving/

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930119/remote-api-for-docker-exec-commands) But i don't know where to write these commands. I am completely new to the API and everything.

P.S: I don't want to use kubernetes

Comment: What is your command to run the Docker container?

Comment: `docker start <Container ID>` to start the container and `docker attach <container ID>`  to get inside the container. Finally i type `python client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000`  inside the container  to produce output

Comment: i actually followed this blog to create and run containers https://weiminwang.blog/2017/09/12/introductory-guide-to-tensorflow-serving/